# Global variable returns null after click event

Tags: c#, client-server, tcpclient

I am writing a client-server application in C# but I have a problem. I have start_server and connect_to_server buttons in the same form. I am trying to add all connected clients into a list when connect_to_server button is clicked. Client can be added into list in connect_to_server button click event but when event is finished list returns null or empty. What can I do? Is the problem about declaring the list variable? Or should I implement something different? Can somebody help me? Thanks.

```
private void btnStartClient_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
         richTextBox1.AppendText("Connected to server!" + "\n");
         m_connectedIpAddresses.Add(((IPEndPoint)sock.Client.LocalEndPoint).Address.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception e1)
    {
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to server");
    }
}

private void btnAnotherButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count = m_connectedIpAddresses.Count;
}
```

'count' variable returns zero. I need number of total connected clients in here.

Comment: You have to post the code for us to figure out. Do you return the list?

Comment: Please post the code as we can't answer your question without it.

Comment: Is the 'connect_to_server' button the 'btnAnotherButton'? When does the 'count' variable return 0, in the same method, or in another one?

Comment: They are two different click events (two different buttons). Connected client is added into list in btnStartClient_Click event but in the second click event, the list seems to be empty.

Comment: Are you sure that btnStartClient_Click() is being called? Assuming Start is clicked before AnotherButton and the vents are bound correctly, then I can't see why count would be 0.

Comment: Yes, I am debugging the code. It goes one by one. I am using threads. Can this make the problem? Or do I need to implement delegates? I need help.

Comment: Is count declared as a global variable? Is that the value that you are checking for 0? It won't change as you have declared a local variable count in btnAnotherButton_Click(), which will hide the global one. That may be the issue.

Comment: As I specified at first, this is a client-server application and I need to run min. two different application (one as server, one as client). I guess this creates the problem, but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The following line declares a *local* variable `count`:

```
int count = m_connectedIpAddresses.Count;
```

even if you have a "global" variable with the same name. Try changing it to:

```
count = m_connectedIpAddresses.Count;
```

This would set the value of the *class* variable `count`. Note that if the variable is declared in a different class, you have to refer to that one of course.

Answer (score 0):

Do you assigned the count as a global variable?

If yes why in btnAnotherButton_Click you declare count as int

Try this

```
int  count = 0;
private void btnStartClient_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
         richTextBox1.AppendText("Connected to server!" + "\n");
         m_connectedIpAddresses.Add(((IPEndPoint)sock.Client.LocalEndPoint).Address.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception e1)
    {
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to server");
    }
}

private void btnAnotherButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    count = m_connectedIpAddresses.Count;
}
```